# Android : Toolbar status bar overlapping

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on creating an app with lollipop toolbar with translucent status bar to have the status bar also tinted. It is working fine with the 
true property.

It is just that the toolbar is overlapping with the status bar now which looks messy. What is the option to position the toolbar below the status bar with maintaining the window translucent status?

Code Snippets :

```
<style name="Theme.XXX" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
      <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
      <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">...</item>
   </style>
```

Toolbar code used in activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/XXX"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.XXX" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: this question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738510/toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar

Answer (score 12):

as **Virus** correctly says, the answer is here: [Toolbar overlapping below status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738510/toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar)

Simply add the attribute

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

into the  xml item and it will work fine :)

Comment: I would not recommend this because there is some side effects with the toast and because the status bar will actually choose a gray color and I'm guessing devs don't want that if they have color for it already. take a better look in this [read](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63653)

Comment: If i have xaml page than what parameter i have to set?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using `fitSystemWindows` property.

Turn off that.

Comment: Thanks but that did not seem to help. I have the following settings in the theme ........<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>......

Answer (score 1):

May be your theme has this

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

comment it out

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep translucent status, you need to have

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Just make the below false

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

and in your parent layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to v21/styles.xml file

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove from all xmls, where it can be found, tag.    fitsSystemWindows
Or set it to false.

Comment: Sorry, what question do you mean.