# Toolbar going underneath status bar both in Activity and Fragment android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to achieve a transparent status bar in pre lollipop and above lollipop as well. My `minimumSdkLevel` is 19. I have tried the following method to achieve transparent `statusbar`. But the `toolbar` is going underneath `statusbar`.

Here is the screenshot (**This is a Full screen Fragment with Toolbar on it**):

[image: **This is a Full screen Fragment**]

Layout of the above `screenshot`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gamesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/gameToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/background_img" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/gameList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is my **`styles.xml`**:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
```

Here is my **`v21/styles.xml`** :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

I have even added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root layout of the `Activities` and `Fragments`.

I have added this below code as well in the `Activities` and `Fragments`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

**Why I am not getting transparent `Statusbar` and why `Toolbar` is going underneath `Statusbar`?**

Comment: Please post your layout

Comment: updated @LangustenGustel

Comment: I think that here is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907616/2819992

Comment: @Hiren check my edited Answer Try using android:fitsSystemWindows in your base view i.e cardView in your Case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolbar overlapping below status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738510/toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar)

Answer (score 0):

in default style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="BGTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="BGTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="BGTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="BGTheme.ActionBar.Transparent.AppBarOverlay" 
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="BGTheme.ActionBar.Transparent.PopupOverlay" 
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and in your v-21 style.xml

```
<style name="BGTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="BGTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** Add this in your root layout `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Answer (score 0):

remove if statment

not work below 21
        `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

Answer (score -2):

add flowing lines in your 'style.xml'

```
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: which version of `style.xml` ?

Comment: The action bar is going away when you set follow code `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

Comment: @Hiren in your default style.xml and its work for me.

Comment: I tried..didn't work for me. can you post the whole solution whatever worked for you. @NirmalShethwala

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:**

try Using the following Line in your Base View.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

as it is mention also 
`android:fitsSystemWindows` is an

> internal attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such
>   as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to leave
>   space for the system windows. Will only take effect if this view is in
>   a non-embedded activity.
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol
>   fitsSystemWindows.

You can also use it globally by using the below line in your theme

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

I hope it helps. It works in my Project.

Comment: By this solution you must write this in every activity. Will generate a bunch of repeated code

Comment: I tried..didn't work for me. can you post the whole solution whatever worked for you.  @Sahil

Comment: hey remove this line if you have this line in your themes
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
and also add the following and try please once more. 
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
@Hiren removing the translucent status will make it work,but i think thats your primary need in your app? Right ?